# Trying to generate a button-based interface in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, onclick, iteration

I am trying to build an interface with javascript. The interface is a grid of buttons. Each row is a different musical instrument and on each column you have a rhythm pattern you can trigger.

When the user click on a button, I want it to change its class so the background-color changes, telling to user it's been activated.

The problem is, my script is always targeting the last button of a row. When I try to force it to target a specific button (which is NOT the last button), it says the button in "undefined".

```
pattern1 = ["Clave 1",[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],"description"];
pattern2 = ["Clave 2",[1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],"description"];
pattern3 = ["Clave 3",[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1],"description"];
pattern4 = ["Clave 4",[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],"description"];
pattern5 = ["Clave 5",[1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],"description"];
pattern6 = ["Clave 6",[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],"description"];
pattern7 = ["Clave 7",[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],"description"];
pattern8 = ["Clave 8",[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],"description"];

var pattern_collection = [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3, pattern4, pattern5, pattern7, pattern8];


function generate_buttons(instrument_id) {
    for (var key in pattern_collection)
    {
        //creating an array of button for each instrument
        var button = new Array();

        //creating the button label
        var button_text;
        button_text = document.createTextNode(pattern_collection[key][0]);

        //creating the button in the DOM
        button[key] = document.createElement('div');

        //by default, the first pattern is shown as playing
        if (pattern_collection[key]==pattern1)
            button[key].className = "isplaying_pattern_button";
        else
            button[key].className = "notplaying_pattern_button";

        button[key].onclick = function() {
        //picking the currently playing button to change its class to not playing
        var playing_button = document.querySelector("#"+instrument_id+" .isplaying_pattern_button");
        playing_button.className = "notplaying_pattern_button";
        //this is where the problem occurs: the script is always targeting the last button of the row
        button[key].className = "isplaying_pattern_button";
        };

        button[key].appendChild(button_text);
        var instrument_patterns = document.getElementById(instrument_id);
        instrument_patterns.appendChild(button[key]);


    }
}
```

Comment: Use a regular `for` loop to iterate arrays, not `for..in`. See if that changes anything.

Comment: Try two things: 1) use `for(;i<array.length;i++)` instead of `for..in` on array; 2) `button[key].onclick=(function(btn){return function(){...};})(button[key]);`.